# scipy.sparse.linalg: what's the difference between splu and factorized?

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, equation-solving

What's the difference between using

```py
 scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized(A)
```

and

```py
 scipy.sparse.linalg.splu(A)
```

Both of them return objects with `.solve(rhs)` method and for both it's said in the documentation that they use LU decomposition. I'd like to know the difference in performance for both of them.

More specificly, I'm writing a python/numpy/scipy app that implements dynamic FEM model. I need to solve an equation `Au = f` on each timestep. A is sparse and rather large, but doesn't depend on timestep, so I'd like to invest some time beforehand to make iterations faster (there may be thousands of them). I tried using `scipy.sparse.linalg.inv(A)`, but it threw memory exceptions when the size of matrix was large. I used `scipy.linalg.spsolve` on each step until recently, and now am thinking on using some sort of decomposition for better performance. So if you have other suggestions aside from LU, feel free to propose!

Comment: Quick glance at the code, so take it with a grain of salt: they are doing the same and `factorized` will forward the calculation to splu; [except](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c578bd0/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L419) for the case you got an umfpack install available and set the right parameter.

Comment: If your `A` is positive-deinite (which is usual for FEM ?),
a Cholesky decomposion `LL'` with
[sksparse.cholmod](https://scikit-sparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cholmod.html)
will take advantage of that -- robust and fast.
I'd suggest 
`fac = cholesky_AAt( At, beta=1e-6 or so ); x = fac.solve_A( At.dot( b ))`
to guard against tiny eigenvalues < 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should both work well for your problem, assuming that `A` does not change with each time step.

`scipy.sparse.linalg.inv(A)` will return a dense matrix that is the same size as `A`, so it's no wonder it's throwing memory exceptions.

`scipy.linalg.solve` is also a dense linear solver, which isn't what you want.

Assuming `A` is sparse, to solve `Au=f` and you only want to solve `Au=f` once, you could use `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`.  For example

```
u = spsolve(A, f)
```

If you want to speed things up dramatically for subsequent solves, you would instead use `scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized` or `scipy.sparse.linalg.splu`. For example

```
A_inv = splu(A)
for t in range(iterations):
    u_t = A_inv.solve(f_t)
```

or

```
A_solve = factorized(A)
for t in range(iterations):
    u_t = A_solve(f_t)
```

They should both be comparable in speed, and much faster than the previous options.

As @sascha said, you will need to dig into the documentation to see the differences between splu and factorize.  But, you can use 'umfpack' instead of the default 'superLU' if you have it installed and set up correctly. I think umfpack will be faster in most cases.  Keep in mind that if your matrix A is too large or has too many non-zeros, an LU decomposition / direct solver may take too much memory on your system. In this case, you might be stuck with using an iterative solver such as [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.cg.html).  Unfortunately, you wont be able to reuse the solve of A at each time step, but you might be able to find a good preconditioner for A (approximation to inv(A)) to feed the solver to speed it up.